Mocking chrome extension runtime API
I want to unit test my background script using jest, I have a function which adds a listener for sent messages. Testing initialiseBackground is simple enough, but as handleNewMessage is not exported nor I think it should be I want to test it as part of this unit. The idea would be that in my test I would:

call initialiseBackground() which adds the listener
Somehow send the message so the listener is triggered

My background script:
export function initialiseBackground() {
    chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(handleNewMessage);
}
initialiseBackground()


function handleNewMessage(message, sender, onSuccess) {
    switch (message.action) {
        case ACTIONS.ONE:
            one(onSuccess);
            return true;
        case ACTIONS.TWO:
            two(message);
            return;
        case ACTIONS.THREE:
            three(message, sender);
            return;
        default:
            console.warn('Action not found:', message.action);
    }
}

So far I've done mocks using a mock file that I add in jest config
global.chrome = {
    runtime: {
        sendMessage: jest.fn(), //trigger listener
        onMessage: {
            addListener: jest.fn(), //set listener
        },
    },
    storage: {
        local: {
            set: jest.fn(),
            get: jest.fn(),
        },
    },
};

Is what I want to accomplish even doable or is there a better approach to handling this?
